# Xcode storyboard seque loops back to the same view

Tags: xcode, loops, view, error-handling, storyboard

I am using storyboard seques to change views to other parts of my app but when I linked my main view to the next and called for the seque in the function within my enter button it just loops back to my main view and refreshes the app.

Here is my function call:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Enter" sender:self];
```

In the storyboard I have my main view linked to the next view with the identifier "Enter" but I still get send back to the same view. Is there any way to specify the destination of the next view? Do I need a certain variable from the other view controllers the need to be imported to the code of the main view controller?

I can provide more code or information if needed.

Picture: http://i1180.photobucket.com/albums/x411/Ryute88/screen.jpg

Identity Inspector Picture: http://i1180.photobucket.com/albums/x411/Ryute88/screen2.jpg

Picture 3: http://i1180.photobucket.com/albums/x411/Ryute88/screen3.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this site: [All about storyboarding](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboarding_%28iPhone_iOS_5%29#Configuring_Storyboard_Segues)

You will find details on doing your stuff.Try that and check if the problem still exists!

Comment: I did everything on that page but it still loops back to the same view even when the seque points to the next view.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the storyboard with IdentityInspector opened in XCode?

Comment: I posted a link in the question to the pic. Ignore the question marks they are supposed to be linked to pictures that I am working on.

Comment: I have not told you to upload this. Please check this image for what I would like to see to help you : http://www.use.com/06bb6406d784f9d05295

Comment: I'm sorry. I just uploaded what you wanted but nothing is really shown in the identity inspector it just says not applicable.

Comment: I think you have somehow created a loop in between your view controllers.In each of your screenshot you have failed to show which segue you are selecting so far.Do one more thing.Extend the space of the storyboard,the view controllers and the segue you are talking about;drag them to give some extra space in between them and take them a bit far from other controllers so that they can be differentiated.Then take the screenshot.And try selecting the segue again and press Identity Inspector.A suggestion: Why not you create another segue and connect those 2 controllers? It's easy :)

Comment: I tried making a new seque, connecting a different button to the next view but it still looped. But I made a new project and was able to switch views easily with seques but for some reason this current project just loops back. I made the next picture a bit more clearer but still the identity inspector says not applicable.

Comment: I eventualy decided to scrap my current storyboard made a new one and everything worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the write segue to call on the next view e.g. pop can only be used in case of Navigation Controllers. 
In any case the problem will be trivial because storyboards do everything for you.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to make the view go into the next view. I have it set up in the storyboard but the problem is that it loops back to the same view.